# whats a git command to git add -A and git commit --amend in one line?

Tags: git

whats a git command to `git add -A` and `git commit --amend` in one line? Also I don't want to specify message or use multiple lines when amending.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the same message you used on the revision you want to amend, use `--no-edit`. In one line, you can just separate with `;`

```
git add -A; git commit --amend --no-edit
```