# Is there a short for `git add . && git commit --amend`?

Tags: git

I already knew that `git commit -a` is short for `git add -u && git commit`.

So I'm wondering if there is a short for `git add . && git commit --amend` when we have some file modified after the first commit?

---

**EDIT**

Change `git add .` to `git add -u`, which are not the same things.

Comment: Have you tried `git commit -a --amend` ?

Comment: See also [Git add and commit in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4298960/1256452) and [whats a git command to git add -A and git commit --amend in one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44295238/1256452).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I already know that `git commit -a` is a short for `git add . && git commit`

Ah, but it isn't.  Let's get back to this in a moment.

> ... [is there] a short for `git add . && git commit --amend`

No, but `git commit -a --amend` comes somewhat close.

Both of these are better expressed, not as `git add . && git commit options`, but rather as `git add -u && git commit options`.  (There's still a difference if you use a separate `git add`, but it's not as obvious.  I'll describe it lightly in a moment.)

In particular, `git add .` tells Git to add *all files at the current directory and below*.  This includes any *new* (but untracked) files, unless those untracked files are also listed in an exclusion file (`.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` for instance).  But `git commit -a` won't add *new* files: it will only update *already-tracked* files.

(Note: In Git 2.0 and later, `git add -u` adds files anywhere in the working tree, not just at the current level and below; use `git add -u .` to limit this to the current level and below.)

Now, as to the differences between using a separate `git add` and subsequent `git commit`, and using the `-a` flag to `git commit`: there are two that are visible to you:

- First, suppose you change your mind about the commit, and abort it entirely.  In this case, with `git add`, any updates are still *staged for commit*.  You can continue to edit and add files as usual but your existing files, added with a `git add` command, are still added.  But with `git commit -a`, your files are *not* added-for-commit.
- Second, if you have a *pre-commit hook*, what the pre-commit hook will use *as* the index is different.  This gets particularly complicated if you start using the `--only` or `--include` flag as well.  These details are not appropriate for those relatively new to Git, so we won't cover them any further here: just remember that there is a corner-case here with hooks.

Answer (score 3):

`git commit -a` will automatically `git add` changes to all tracked files. You can combine this with the `--amend` flag to get `git commit -a -amend`.